# Get filename when using gulp-ejs

Tags: node.js, gulp, ejs

I am using ejs as a template engine for a static website (Note: I am NOT using express).

For every page on my site, I have an `.ejs` file. I render the templates with gulp using the following in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('build-html', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/views/pages/**/*.ejs)
        .pipe(gulp_ejs())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/'));
});
```

In my `.ejs` template file, I need to get the filename as I need to add it to my canonical link e.g.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://somesite.com/<%= FILENAME %>"/>
```

The problem is I cant work out how to get the filename

I'm using `"gulp-ejs": "1.2.2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst its not documented, a quick look at the source code shoes that `filename` variable is merged with the options hash. The full filename can be pulled in by using the `filename` variable in the `.ejs` file e.g.

```
<p> this is the full filename path <%= filename %> </p>
```